# Read file as matrix in fread

Tags: r, matrix

I am using `fread` in `R` but my file does not have any header names at all. It is a raw file with just the information I need.

If I use `A <- as.matrix(read.table(fname))` then I get all 1000 rows, but it is slower. However, when I use `A <- as.matrix(fread(fname))` it is faster but only returns 999 rows.

Is there a way to get `fread` to return everything just like `read.table` would? I have searched the documentation but am unable to find anything.

Comment: Set `header = F` in your `fread` to match the `read.table` default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gregor mentioned, fread has an argument "header" which defaults to true if all of the entries in the first row are character type fields. When you ran fread it most likely assumed the first row of data contained column names and the remaining 999 rows were data. I couldn't say for sure without seeing the data you're importing, though.

This should do the trick for you:

```
    A <- as.matrix(fread(fname, header = FALSE))
```